# Generating nodekey via geth init

Tags: go-ethereum

The `geth init --datadir node/ genesis.json` command generates an empty keystore directory and a geth directory. Its only after running the node that the geth folder is populated with the nodekey. Is it possible to generate the node.key file via the `geth init` command? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bootnode` utility for this to create a nodekey immediately after geth init. You can download it with "Geth & Tools" from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

```
bootnode -genkey <datadir>/geth/nodekey
```

If you wish to get the public key for the enode url, you can use:

```
bootnode -nodekey <datadir>/geth/nodekey -writeaddress
```

Comment: How is this method using  `geth init`? It just generates a private key and gives the public key for it. Can you tell how this can be applied on the node's directory after running `geth init genesis.json`? Or any other method?

Comment: When you start the node it will take the datadir/geth/nodekey file. So you can just create it infront with bootnode. I've edited the answer. Hope it helps.